# How to convert dynamic to unknown class in runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime

I have a dynamic rule engine and i want to pass class to this and each time the class is sent differently.

For example:

```
Order MyOrder = new Order()
{
  OrderId = 1,
  Customer = new Customer()
  {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Country = new Country()
    {
      CountryCode = "AUS"
    }
  },
  Items = new List<Item>(){
    new Item(){ ItemCode = "MM23", Cost=5.25M},
    new Item(){ ItemCode = "LD45", Cost=5.25M},
    new Item(){ ItemCode = "Test", Cost=3.33M},
  }
};
```

I want to change this:

```
var compiledRule = engine.CompileRule<Order>(rule);
```

to :

```
dynamic obj = MyOrder;
var compiledRule = engine.CompileRule<?????>(rule);
```

how can I get Type of obj and put instead of  "????"

Comment: Just in case this is a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you take a step back and explain **why** you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after search a lot

```
var engine = new MRE();
var compiledRule = engine.CompileRule<Order>(rule);
```

change to:

```
var engine = new MRE();    
var compiledRule = typeof(MRE).GetMethod("CompileRule").MakeGenericMethod(myOrder.GetType())
                        .Invoke(engine, new object[] { rule}) as dynamic;
```